# Clickhouse materialized view with TO clause doesn't support partition by

Tags: clickhouse

I use *TO* syntax to move the data from a materialized view to a table. Since, I have a need to periodically cleanup old partitions from materialized view, I tried below syntax without success:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW counter_daily_mv
 TO counter_daily
 ENGINE = MergeTree()
 PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(day) ORDER BY (device, count)
AS SELECT
    when as day,
    device,
    value as count
FROM counter
```

But PARTITION BY works without *TO* (see below). How can I work around so that I can use *TO* clause and still cleanup materialized view efficiently?

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW counter_daily_mv
ENGINE = MergeTree()
 PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(day) ORDER BY (device, count)
AS SELECT
    when as day,
    device,
    value as count
FROM counter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior: for the existing table that defined in TO-expression cannot be redefined table's properties which already been defined in its CREATE-clause.

MV with *TO* does *not* store any data, it just inserts it to table defined in *TO*.

It needs to either define the [TTL-clause](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#mergetree-table-ttl) for a table defined in *TO* to automate removing extra data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_source_data
(
    `id` Int32,
    `ts` DateTime
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(ts)
ORDER BY id

CREATE TABLE test_mv_storage
(
    `id` Int32,
    `ts` DateTime
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(ts)
ORDER BY id
TTL ts + INTERVAL 1 MONTH DELETE

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_mv TO test_mv_storage
AS
SELECT *
FROM test_source_data
WHERE id > 10
```

or create 'storable' MV with TTL (i would prefer this way as more compact):

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_source_data
(
    `id` Int32,
    `ts` DateTime
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(ts)
ORDER BY id

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_mv_2
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(ts)
ORDER BY id 
TTL ts + INTERVAL 1 MONTH DELETE
AS
SELECT *
FROM test_source_data
WHERE id > 10
```

Under the hood for the second case, CH creates the hidden table for MV *.inner.test_mv_2* (call *show tables from db* to see it).

---

see for details [Putting Things Where They Belong Using New TTL Moves](https://altinity.com/blog/2020/3/23/putting-things-where-they-belong-using-new-ttl-moves).